# Как извлечь дату из ячейки?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, datetime

Имею датафрейм со стлобцами, где в ячейках следующее содержание 3/4 от 23.03.2021, 1/670 от 20.07.2021 и тд. Необходимо извлечь только конец, то есть дату. Пробовал через partition, extract, пробовал пилить ячейку и забирать последний инденкс, но тщетно. В RegEx понимаю мало, хотя скорее всего им это и решается.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рабочий пример с использованием [Series.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
In [126]: df
Out[126]:
                   col
0    3/4 от 23.03.2021
1  1/670 от 20.07.2021

In [127]: df["dt"] = df["col"].str.extract(r"\b(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\b")[0]

In [128]: df
Out[128]:
                   col          dt
0    3/4 от 23.03.2021  23.03.2021
1  1/670 от 20.07.2021  20.07.2021
```

PS на будущее - всегда приводите в вопросе [воспроизводимый пример данных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/) и результат, который вы хотите получить.